# Which is better practice, using private variables or public methods within the class?

Tags: java, class, methods, setter

Example:

```
private int x = 4;

public TestClass(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public TestClass(int x) {
    setX(x);
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}
```

Is the first constructor better practice or the second? I'm asking this because when I encapsulate my classes in `IntelliJ IDEA` if I used `this.x = x` before, it changes it to `setX(int newX);`.

Comment: I'd usually prefer the direct assignment because it saves an extra stack operation. I usually only use methods when they have more complicated behaviour than just assigning values.

Comment: Arguably calling `setX(int)` is more unpredictable, since it can be overridden by any sub-classes. `setX(int)` should probably be `final` to prevent this; unless the intention is to allow this to be changed.

Comment: I think making getters and setter for each and every field and simply to access it within the containing class is an overkill. so personally I'd stick with the first example `this.x = x;`. but of course one could argue it depends on the situation.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw if it has a need to be read-and-write then I disagree.

Comment: Having extra logic in a setter is highly discouraged, setters should just set the field value with given parameter - if you want additional logic, call the method with a descriptive name. Concerning the extra stack operation/slight performance hit by calling a method instead of directly accessing the field - I don't think that in reality there would be any impact, because of JVM / JIT optimizations, the method call could be inlined...

Comment: I would delay using accessors inside your constructors until there's some actual benefit.  It introduces unnecessary complexity like requiring private setters for immutable objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most part, it's all personal preference.  I would use the first constructor if its value did not depend on other variables.  However, setter methods allow for certain conditions to be met before modifying the value of a variable.  For example:

```
private int x;

public TestClass(int x) {
    setX(x);
}

public void setX(int x) {
    // Some random condition depending on other variables.
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() & 1 == 0) {
        this.x = 5;
    } else {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

It would make sense to use a setter method if there were many conditions that could not be easily represented by a ternary statement.

If the class is abstract, then a concrete class that extends it could possibly override the setter method, thus modifying the value of the variable.  If you plan on using self-encapsulation and don't want any child class to override the setter method, simply add the `final` keyword to the method declaration.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

The derived classes can override the setter, and **you** need to decide if the effects of the override are good or bad in a particular place.

My opinion is that if the setter is documented to be overridable, you need to pay attention to using setter vs. the assignment. If you do not document the setter to be overridable, then just use the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

There is a term called `Self Encapsulation`. Martin Fowler wrote a blog on this topic. [Blog Link](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/SelfEncapsulation.html). To summarize this sometime you may have initialization or assign logic in the `setter`. So I think, it is better to call `setter` whenever you are going to initialize or assign value.

Comment: A very interesting a blog post. Never thought about that concept before. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You've already accepted an answer, but still, I see something nobody has mentioned.  A setter makes your class mutable (at least without guard conditions), which may or may not be a good thing.  However, it's much easier to make your class immutable if you supply the value to the constructor.

Immutable classes are inherently thread-safe, and should be preferred whenever practical.  So in your (admittedly extra simple) example, I would favor using the constructor, and I would have only a getter for the value.

IMO, having a constructor that takes a value *and* a setter that sets that same value is a code aroma if not smell.